# How to debug Angular 2 with webpack?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

Given the following error:

**EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter
TypeError: Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter**

The stack trace that I get is huge and I have no clue which typescript file is choking that has a read only property. Is there a way that will tell me which property it is trying to set that has only a getter?

A quick and dirty solution is to one by one remove code until it works. I would be able to tell which scope of the code it was choking and what would be the problem there. However, if in the long run the code suddenly breaks, then his kind of solution is not ideal and I would have no idea what broke it without looking at the version histories.

Is there a tool that would help me with this?

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter
TypeError: Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter
    at assignAll (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:16015:29)
    at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:16086:16)
    at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:5256:16)
    at ViewWrappedError.WrappedError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:5318:16)
    at new ViewWrappedError (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:57044:16)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:79673:23)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:79646:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:79433:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_ReportsComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/ReportsModule/ReportsComponent/host.ngfactory.js:35:19)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:79448:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:79643:44)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:57990:20)
    at RouterOutlet.activate (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:63236:42)
    at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:21937:16)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:21904:26)
    at http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:21840:58
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:21840:29)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:21910:22)
    at http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:21840:58
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:21840:29)
    at ActivateRoutes.activate (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:21814:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:21382:22
    at SafeSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:4169:25)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:6028:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:5977:22)
    at Subscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:5930:26)
    at Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:5894:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:23024:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:5894:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:22890:30)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:85350:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:5894:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:23024:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:5894:18)
    at ReduceSubscriber._complete (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:86357:30)
    at ReduceSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:5919:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._complete (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:22882:30)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:5919:18)
    at ArrayObservable._subscribe (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:66973:24)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:4131:27)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:22832:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:4128:22)
    at ReduceOperator.call (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:86316:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:4128:22)
    at MapOperator.call (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:22995:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:4128:22)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:46412:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:22877:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:22874:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:22857:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:5894:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:22890:30)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:85350:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:5894:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:23024:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:5894:18)
    at EverySubscriber.notifyComplete (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:67454:26)
    at EverySubscriber._complete (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:67471:14)
    at EverySubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:5919:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._complete (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:22882:30)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:5919:18)
    at ArrayObservable._subscribe (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:66973:24)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:4131:27)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:22832:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:4128:22)
    at EveryOperator.call (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:67434:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:4128:22)
    at MapOperator.call (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:22995:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:4128:22)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:46412:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:22877:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:22874:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:22857:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:5894:18)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

It fixed in **0.7.6**

https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#076-2017-01-17

**Previous version**

Downgrade zonejs to **0.7.4** https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/595

```
npm install --save zone.js@0.7.4
```

Comment: Thank you that fixes it. Just a side question, do you know why there's a HUGE error trace that the error_handler.js spits out? Is there a way to limit it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is a missing library or module. In one of your templates you're using a directive which is not known to the application (Hasn't been loaded);

How I've resolved this.

- Check the error stack in your browser
- Then check for methods: e.g. CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass the Locals
  ==> There you can see a meaningful error message which leads you directly to the missing directive

Comment: This error is not related to "zone.js"; Maybe the error message changes if you change the "zone.js" version

Comment: It is actually related to zone.js. I downgraded my version and it now at least gives me better error message.

Comment: That'S what I meant. You get a different error message but your error remains. Check the error stack in the console to get to to the error message which is actually the problem