# Error in template: Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter

Tags: angular

I have a component as below where I retrieve a Course object:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {CourseService} from "../shared/course.service";
import {Course} from "../shared/Course";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-course-list',
  templateUrl: './course-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-list.component.css']
})

export class CourseListComponent implements OnInit {

  course : Course;
  name : string;

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.courseService.getCourse(1).subscribe(response => {
      this.course = response;
      this.name = this.course.name;
      console.log(this.course);
    });
  }
}
```

The retrieval looks to work. Why do I get an error in the template when I try to do:

```
<p>
  Editing Course : {{course.name}} < -error
  Editing Course : {{name}} <-- works
</p>
```

Error:

```
error_handler.js:50EXCEPTION: Error in ./CourseListComponent class CourseListComponent - inline template:0:3 caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:50
(anonymous) @ application_ref.js:259
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:242
onInvoke @ ng_zone.js:269
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:241
Zone.run @ zone.js:113
(anonymous) @ zone.js:535
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:275
onInvokeTask @ ng_zone.js:260
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:274
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:151
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:433
error_handler.js:52ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:52
(anonymous) @ application_ref.js:259
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:242
onInvoke @ ng_zone.js:269
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:241
Zone.run @ zone.js:113
(anonymous) @ zone.js:535
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:275
onInvokeTask @ ng_zone.js:260
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:274
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:151
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:433
error_handler.js:55ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:55
(anonymous) @ application_ref.js:259
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:242
onInvoke @ ng_zone.js:269
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:241
Zone.run @ zone.js:113
(anonymous) @ zone.js:535
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:275
onInvokeTask @ ng_zone.js:260
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:274
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:151
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:433
error_handler.js:56TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_CourseListComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/CourseListComponent/component.ngfactory.js:34:87)
```

Comment: Firstly check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705887/how-to-debug-angular-2-with-webpack/41705957#41705957 After that you will see the origin error

Comment: Thanks. That cleans up the stacktrace however I am still not understanding the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting data asynchronously. As at the first time your `course` variable is `undefined` you can use safe navigation operator (?.) to prevent this error

```
{{course?.name}}
```

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator

Comment: Thanks. That fixes the issue. Is there any alternative (more correct) approach or is this standard? Data is coming from a Server call. Pretty new to all this client side UI stuff.

Comment: Alternative option is using `ngIf` Save navigation operator(Elvis) is more preferable solution in such cases

Comment: Angular 1 would put the blank there for you until the data arrived -- Angular 2 forces you to allow this.  yurzui is right that the elvis operator is your best bet in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting this error in a unit test run. The issue was a missing directive in the test case.